# Import orders file on magento enterprise or community (product with customs options)

Tags: php, import, magento

We need to import some orders file on magento enterprise.
In our file, products contains customs Options.

We tried to make an extension but we have some problems to import Customs options.
The import of standard product is successful but not for the product with customs options.

For customs option, missing "info_buyRequest" valu in database.

The technical support of magento we responded "the import process currently can't handle importing products with custom options".

Magento use custom options when ordering a product with customs options on website.

What features do magento use to fill in the fields "info_buyRequest" and "Product_options" when ordering?

Have you see a extension pack for import file order with product contains customs options?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: very few people have Magento enterprise version. Where are you getting this error? while using the API?

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for reply.
We have magento enterprise and magento community.
For both, there is no function to import order file with product contains customs options.

Magento build a "info_buyRequest" field when oredering on web site.
But we don't know how...
We want to use the same function to build "info_buyRequest" when we import file order.

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Magento API or any built-in tool but you can try to check this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bolasevich/extension/1894/custom-bulk-product-import-with-tier-pricing--product-custom-options--configurable-products which is supposed to support custom options importing.